# How to make commands available in Cygwin (x86)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, cygwin, bash

I'd like to use Cygwin for windows because I prefer the linux style command prompt over windows cmd. My question is how can I make the `rc` command (program) available in cygwin, so when I type `rc` from cygwin it just works. It's currently available only through Visual Studio Developer command prompt but not in cygwin.

The program is located here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\rc.exe

I am assuming I should be editing my .bashrc file? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re a masochist who loves extra typing, you could provide the full Unix-format path for the command (`/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/8.0/bin/x86/rc`) each time you want to run the command.

To save having to specify the full path of the command, add the directory containing the `rc` program to the `PATH` environment variable (which is used to search for executable programs). The following command appends the Unix format of this directory path to the PATH:

```
PATH=$PATH:"$(cygpath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86')"
```

To save having to type this each time Cygwin starts, you can modify a shell start-up file. With a default Cygwin installation, this is best done by adding the above command to the end of `~/.bash_profile`.

Another option would be to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\` to the Windows `PATH` environment variable – which is inherited by Cygwin when it starts.

Comment: I guess you need to escape also `(` and `)`

Comment: Thanks @matzeri  I've escaped the unquoted parentheses.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyGeoghegan I've added RC path to PATH, and it works great